# Как узнать используемую память

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как можно узнать сколько памяти занимает выполнение программы или класса в Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой инструмент как **jmap**, выводящий гистограмму с показателями сколько памяти занимают объекты и т.п.

---

Также, утилиту **jstat** можно использовать для сбора самых разнообразных статистических данных. Статистика jstat сортируется в "свойства", указанные первым параметром командной строки. Чтобы увидеть список свойств, нужно запустить jstat с параметром -options. 
В документации утилиты в JDK говорится, что именно показывает каждое из свойств, но большинство из них используется для сбора информации о работе сборщика мусора или его компонентов. Свойство -class показывает загруженные и выгруженные классы (что делает утилиту полезной для обнаружения утечек ClassLoader в пределах сервера приложений или вашего кода), а -compiler и -printcompilation предоставляют сведения о JIT-компиляторе Hotspot.
По умолчанию jstat отображает информацию по состоянию на момент обращения. Если нужны регулярные снимки текущего состояния, укажите после -свойств интервалы в миллисекундах. jstat будет постоянно отображать снимки текущего состояния контролируемого процесса. Если нужно, чтобы jstat сделал лишь определенное количество снимков, укажите его за значением интервала/периода.

Answer (score 1):

Можете включить индекатор памяти в

`File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Appearance`

поставить галочку в `Show Memory Indecator`

[ссылка](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/appearance.html)

Comment: Это покажет, сколько жрет сама idea, а не написанный в ней код

Answer (score 1):

Можно запустить java с выводом данных gc, например -verbose:gc параметр, посмотреть что он будет выводить, там данных будет достаточно.

Второй вариант, использовать jstat